# Get Image Description

Tags: images, captions

I'm trying to make a post split in 2 columns. The first and left one is going to be any image inside the post, and the second and right one will be `the_content()` (excluding the images).

So as of now I have no problem pulling all the images. However - I can't seem to get the image caption or title or description.

Heres my code:

```
<?php if ( $images = get_posts(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    )))
    {
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, full );
            $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
            $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );
            $i++;
            if (!empty($imageTitle)) {
                echo '<div class="client-img-item ci-'.$count++.'"><img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt="'.$imageTitle.'"  /> <div class="CAPS client-img-caption"><span class="red arrow-lrg">»</span> '.$imageDescription.'</div></div><div class="sml-dots"></div>';
} else { echo '<img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt="" />' ; }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Image Found';
    }?>
```

Comment: As of WordPress 3.5.0 `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $attachment )`  will do the trick :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

$attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
return array(
    'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ),
    'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,
    'description' => $attachment->post_content,
    'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),
    'src' => $attachment->guid,
    'title' => $attachment->post_title
);
}
```

[Source](http://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/functions-to-get-an-attachments-caption-title-alt-description#post-22155)

As [sporkme explains](http://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/functions-to-get-an-attachments-caption-title-alt-description#post-23960) later in the thread, this is dumped into your **functions.php** and can then be called with `$attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment(your_attachment_id);`.

Comment: come from : //https://gist.github.com/hullen/5443218 ????