# How I can get image description/title/alt for gallery image?

Tags: gallery, captions, description

I'm displaying a gallery image but I also want display the caption for image. I can get the info that we insert when us upload a image in WordPress Dashboard like  "Title/Caption/ALT/Description". I want get anyone and display.

```
<?php    
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );
    foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) :    
?>                                

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_url ?>'); background-size: cover">
        <div class="caption">                
            <!-- Here I want display the Title/Caption/ALT/Description of image -->
            <h2><?php echo $image_url->"DESCRIPTION/TITLE/ALT"; ?> </h2>
        </div>                                        
    </div>
```

Reading at the docs of [get_post_gallery_images](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images) I didn't find a solution for my issue. 
I also found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125554/get-image-description) but I don't know if it works and I've erros to implement in my code.

Anyway, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `metadata` of each image, add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function get_post_gallery_images_with_info($postvar = NULL) {
    if(!isset($postvar)){
        global $post;
        $postvar = $post;//if the param wasnt sent
    }


    $post_content = $postvar->post_content;
    preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
    $images_id = explode(",", $ids[1]); //we get the list of IDs of the gallery as an Array


    $image_gallery_with_info = array();
    //we get the info for each ID
    foreach ($images_id as $image_id) {
        $attachment = get_post($image_id);
        array_push($image_gallery_with_info, array(
            'alt' => get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true),
            'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,
            'description' => $attachment->post_content,
            'href' => get_permalink($attachment->ID),
            'src' => $attachment->guid,
            'title' => $attachment->post_title
                )
        );
    }
    return $image_gallery_with_info;
}
```

use it in your logic like this:

```
<?php    
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images_with_info($post); //you can use it without params too
    foreach( $gallery as $image_obj ) :    
?>                                

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_obj['src'] ?>'); background-size: cover">
        <div class="caption">                
            <!-- Here I want display the Title/Caption/ALT/Description of image -->
            <h2><?php echo $image_obj['title']." ". $image_obj['caption']." ".$image_obj['description']; ?> </h2>
        </div>                                        
    </div>
<?php    
endforeach;
?>
```

it will output like this:

[image]

each image returned by the function is an array like this:

```
Array
        (
            [alt] => Alt Coffe
            [caption] => Caption coffe
            [description] => Description coffe
            [href] => http://yoursite/2017/02/14/hello-world/coffee/
            [src] => http://yoursite/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/02/coffee.jpg
            [title] => coffee
        )
```

notice `href` and `src` are different, one is the permalink and the other the direct `URL`.

Comment: Amazing! Very simple and clean. Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: I am new to wordpress and php - where did you insert this part of the code

Comment: @Yebach this works with a post object that has a image gallery, the function goes to `functions.php` and the logic into any singular template where you can provide a `post` object to the function

Answer (score 2):

The caption for an image is actually meta_data attached to the image and the [get_post_gallery_images only returns a url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery_images/), so in the array you won't have any other information.

You could try something like:

```
<?php    
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );
    foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) :  

    //get the id of the image post.
    $image_id = url_to_postid( $image_url ) 
    //get the image "post" information
    $image = get_post($image_id);
    //get the image title
    $image_title = $image->post_title;
    //get the image caption
    $image_caption = $image->post_excerpt;

?>                                

    <div class="item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_url ?>'); background-size: cover">
        <div class="caption">                
            <!-- Here I want display the Title/Caption/ALT/Description of image -->
            <h2><?php echo $image_caption; ?> </h2>
        </div>                                        
    </div>
```